# Mobile video selection for editing - with or without preview?

Tags: usability, mobile, interaction-design, user-behavior, user-expectation

We are creating a mobile video editing app for **iOS**. When user opens the app he (obviously) needs to select the video he wants to edit. We couldn't agree on what experience will work better - with video preview with autoplay or show only thumbnails. What do you think?

[image]

**Would love to hear your exprience on this one. Much appreciated.**

**Best Regards, Roi**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1 is more clear and is using a pattern most apps are already using.

Is there a specific reason why you want to use autoplay instead of giving the user the choice to play the video if he wants to before selecting it?

Im assuming if you are using autoplay you will have the video on mute by default? So you would need to add an unmute to that screen.

Also it might make sense to include a function that lets the user scroll through the video-timeline and select a specific range he wants to import.

Comment: Yap, that's what I thought also. I'll implement those. Thank you! :)